# Azure Data Factory connect to Azure PostreSQL (Flexible Server) without password, with User Assigned Managed Entity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-postgresql, password-less

It's possible to connect to Flexible Server Azure PostgreSQL with Azure Data Factory with UAMI?

I'm already added the Managed Entity to ADF and created a Credential with it in the Factory Studio, but can't see any option at Linked Services to use it with Azure PostreSQL.
With Spring Boot and java services was able to connect to it.

Comment: As you can see in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql?tabs=data-factory) there is no other authentication option is provided, so it is not possible to connect to Azure PostreSQL (Flexible Server) User Assigned Managed Entity to Azure Data Factory.

Comment: But you can raise a feature request, here are some similar ones already raised: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f30d5380-29e3-ed11-a81c-0022485030d1. You can raise one asking specifically support for UAMI and SAMI.